# PHP - average of array values based on datetime interval

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, average, intervals

I have the following:

```
[1]=>
array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["sensorId"]=>
    int(52)
    ["dateTime"]=>
    string(20) "2018-03-04T22:40:32Z"
    ["value"]=>
    float(50)
  }
[2]=>
array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["sensorId"]=>
    int(52)
    ["dateTime"]=>
    string(20) "2018-03-04T22:49:32Z"
    ["value"]=>
    float(40)
  }
[3]=>
array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["sensorId"]=>
    int(52)
    ["dateTime"]=>
    string(20) "2018-03-04T23:05:32Z"
    ["value"]=>
    float(10)
  }
[4]=>
array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["sensorId"]=>
    int(52)
    ["dateTime"]=>
    string(20) "2018-03-04T23:25:32Z"
    ["value"]=>
    float(65)
  }
```

I would like to get the average of the values per time interval (hour in this case), so:

[image]

I can't find what kind of combination of functions I need to use for the problem.

Comment: You would need to loop over the data, convert the dates and sum the values.  Make a start and I'm sure others will help fix any bigs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the best solution in performance, but you can start with it. Group the values by date and finally calculate the averages.

```
$values = [
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "sensorId" => 52,
        "dateTime" => "2018-03-04T22:40:32Z",
        "value" => 50.0
    ],
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "sensorId" => 52,
        "dateTime" => "2018-03-04T22:49:32Z",
        "value" => 40,
    ],
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "sensorId" => 52,
        "dateTime" => "2018-03-04T23:05:32Z",
        "value" => 10,
    ], 
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "sensorId" => 52,
        "dateTime" => "2018-03-04T23:25:32Z",
        "value" => 65,
    ],
];

$groupedValues = [];

foreach ($values as $value) {
    $dateKey = (new DateTime($value['dateTime']))->format('Y-m-d H');

    if (empty($groupedValues[$dateKey])) {
        $groupedValues[$dateKey] = [
            'total' => $value['value'],
            'count' => 1
        ];
    } else {
        $groupedValues[$dateKey]['total'] += $value['value'];
        $groupedValues[$dateKey]['count'] += 1;
    }
}

foreach ($groupedValues as $date => $group) {
    $average = $group['total'] / $group['count'];
    echo "{$date} = {$average} \n";
}
```

Result:

```
2018-03-04 22 = 45 
2018-03-04 23 = 37.5
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2ac4d8f557dd4d2184ab173206b5cac09edf31636)

Comment: Thanks! this works!